# Fluent Validation not Working in Bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages, fluentvalidation

I was using data annotation validation on my Razor Pages which worked fine. For more complex valitaion I am using Fluent Validation, which works fine for everything unless it is in a Modal.

```
    public class MyModel
{

    [RegularExpression(@"^Test|Prod", ErrorMessage = "Please Choose A Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    }

public class MyValidator : MyValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Username)
            .Empty()
            .When(support => x.Found == false)
            .WithMessage("Not Found");
        RuleFor(x => x.IsComplete)
            .Must(x => x.Equals(true))
            .WithMessage("Please confirm");
    }
}
```

Below is example modal code - I have simiplified it so sorry for any mistakes. The code in the main body validates fine, but nothing I put in a modal with Fluent Validation works - it is just submitted without checks. I have several modals all doing the same thing. Data annotation validation works fine.

```
<div id="" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">    
    <div class="modal-dialog-700" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-size">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Test</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                    <form asp-page-handler="update" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="MyModel.Username" class="control-label">Test Code</label>
                            <textarea asp-for="MyModel.Username" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MyModel.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn">
                                <span class="text">Update</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I have also tried:

```
        RuleFor(support => support.Found.ToString())
            .Matches(@"^True$")
```

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is that `FluentValidation` does **not** support **all** rules for client side validation.

Quoted from [FluentValidation docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#clientside-validation):

> Note that **not all** rules defined in FluentValidation will work with ASP.NET’s **client-side validation**. For example, any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side. Nor will any rules in a `RuleSet` (although this can be changed - see the section below on “RuleSet for client-side messages”). The following validators are supported on the client:
>
> ```
> NotNull/NotEmpty
> Matches (regex)
> InclusiveBetween (range)
> CreditCard
> Email
> EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
> MaxLength
> MinLength
> Length
> ```

So this is a behavior by design.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the same rules used in the main body shouldn't be working?

Comment: I am confused because I though the above was server side validation?

Comment: @Hawke "it is just submitted without checks" : the browser submits the form without check because "any rules defined using a condition (with **When**/**Unless**), custom validators, or calls to **Must** will not run on the client side". You need check the ModelState on Serverside or create a custom remote validator .

Comment: I am just confused as to why this works on all the other forms on the page but not the modal. You are correct that it is just .Must() and .When() that do not work, so I am not saying you are wrong. I tried writing a custom validator using data annotations but that doesn't run either (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2013/10/16/aspnet-mvc-required-checkbox-with-data-annotations)

Comment: @Hawke The tutorial you linked above is still validating on server side: if the validation fails, it renders the form with validation message. See "if(!ModelState.IsValid){ ... }" (line 17)

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidation is a server-side framework, and does not provide any client-side validation directly. The following validators are supported on the client:

```
NotNull/NotEmpty
Matches (regex)
InclusiveBetween (range)
CreditCard
Email
EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
MaxLength
MinLength
Length
```

If you want to use validation rules on client-side, you can try FormHelper. Form Helper  transforms server-side validations to client-side.

Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FormHelper

GitHub: https://github.com/sinanbozkus/formhelper